# ¿Como puedo reemplazar %20 y + por - en la url?

Tags: javascript, regex, .htaccess

Me gustaría poder obtener o detectar todos los espacios del tipo `%20` y `+` en la url, y reemplazarlos por `-` usando JavaScript.

Tengo este regex `/[\s\%20\+]/g` pero no sé si realmente funciona, no sé mucho sobre expresiones regulares xD.

Ejemplo con `+`:

```
http://miurl.com/mi+url+web
```

Y quiero que quede así:

```
http://miurl.com/mi-url-web
```

Ejemplo con `%20`:

```
http://miurl.com/mi%20url%20web
```

Y quiero que que así;

```
http://miurl.com/mi-url-web
```

Ejemplo con `+` y `%20`:

```
http://miurl.com/mi+url%20web
```

Y quiero que quede así:

```
http://miurl.com/mi-url-web
```

Aquí añado mis urls con hash:

```
http://miurl.com/#!mi+url%20web
```

Y las manejo con el evento `hashchage` y normalmente osea recargando la página totalmente manualmente, sólo que al corregir las urls con `-` me crea un redireccionamiento infinito. Cree un código referente al que me mostraron aquí, pero haciéndolo con `window.location.hash` me hace el redireccionamiento infinito.

Comment: que pasara con %20? solo quieres obtener la cantidad?, publica un ejemplo de url, y un ejemplo de como quieres que quede porfavor

Comment: Listo, ya puse los ejemplos. Espero puedas ayudarme.

Comment: A esta pregunta le falta incluir una breve descripción de lo buscado/investigado, tal como [ask] propone para redactar una buena pregunta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### JavaScript

Este es el código para reemplazar el hash (fragmento / etiqueta) de una URI. Puede ir en el `<head>` del HTML para que sea lo primero que se ejecute.

```js
//Reemplazar al cargar la página
if (location.hash)
    location.replace(location.hash.replace(/\+|%20/g, "-"));

//Asignar evento cuando se cambie el hash
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(event){
    if (location.hash)
        location.replace(location.hash.replace(/\+|%20/g, "-"));

    //Descomentar para mostrar en consola cuando se dispara
    //console.debug("Se disparó el evento hashchange: ", event.oldURL, "-->", event.newURL);
});
```

Se puede ver que se está reemplazando

1. Apenas se carga la página.
2. Si, durante la navegación, el usuario cambia el fragmento (manualmente o por código).

Descripción del regex:

- `\+` - Un `+` [literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backslash)
  (más en *[special characters](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)*).
- `|` - [Alternancia](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-or) ::: funciona como un `OR`
  (más en *[alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html)*).
- `%20` - Texto `%20` [literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#special-backslash).
- `/g` - [Modificador](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Parameters) `g` ::: buscar todas las ocurrencias ([global](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp#Parameters)).

Demo del regex: https://regex101.com/r/R35zAs/1
Demo del script: http://mariano.uphero.com/50400/#demo+del%20script

Otras opciones para reemplazar espacios:

- `/[+ ]|%20/g` - Para reemplazar también a espacios literales.
- `/(?:[+ ]|%20)+/g` - Para convertir a múltiples *espacios* consecutivos en un solo guión.

> **`location.replace("#hash")` vs. `location.hash = "#hash"`**
>
> Una forma directa de cambiar el hash es con:
>
> ```js
> location.hash = location.hash.replace(/\+|%20/g, "-");
> ```
>
> Sin embargo, esto hace que se agregue en el historial del navegador.
>   Y si reemplazamos `#a+b` por `#a-b`, al navegar hacia atrás (*back*),
>   el código volvería a reemplazar a `#a+b`, haciendo que vuelva automáticamente
>   a la última URI. Es decir, no permitiría volver a la página anterior.
>   Por ese motivo, utilizamos [location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Location/replace), que reemplaza la
>   entrada actual del historial (sin generar una nueva entrada).
>   <sub>* Tal cual el [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50400/como-puedo-reemplazar-20-y-por-en-la-url#comment88992_50444) de [aldanux](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/6491/aldanux), se podría manipular con [history.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Manipulando_el_historial_del_navegador#El_m%C3%A9todo_replaceState()), capturando en [onpopstate](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate).</sub>

---

#### .htaccess

Si además se desea reemplazar los caracteres de la ruta (*pathname*) desde el `.htaccess`, el código sería:

```python
RewriteEngine On

#Reemplazar por la ruta de tu página!!!
RewriteBase /ruta

#Reescribir si tiene 2 o más "%20" o "+"
RewriteRule "^([^+ ]*)[+ ]([^+ ]*[+ ].*?)/*$" $1-$2 [N]
#Redireccionar si tiene 1 "%20" o "+"
RewriteRule "^([^+ ]*)[+ ](.*)" $1-$2 [R,L]
```

**Descripción**

- En el .htaccess, no se reciben `%20`, porque Apache los interpreta directamente como espacios. Por eso, se reemplaza `[+ ]` (un `+` o un espacio).
- La primera regla reemplaza cuando hay más de un caracter, usando el flag `[N]` que hace que se vuelvan a ejecutar todas las reglas (generamos un loop).

  - `^([^+ ]*)[+ ]` - Coincide desde el inicio con **1.** cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no son `+` ni espacios (capturado en `$1`), y **2.** con un caracter `[+ ]`.
  - `([^+ ]*[+ ].*)` - Captura en `$2` **1.** más caracteres que no son `+` ni espacios, **2.** un caracter buscado, y **3.** todo el resto hasta el final.
  - `/*$` - Coincide con una barra al final de la URI, para dejarla fuera del grupo, y no incluirla en la reescritura (si no, se estarían acumulando barras al final por cada espacio reemplazado).
  - Se reemplaza por `$1-$2` - Todo lo que está antes del primer `+` o espacio, un `-` y todo lo que está después.
- La segunda regla es lo mismo, salvo que sólo busca coincidir con un único `+` o espacio (puede haber 1 sólo porque si llegó hasta acá es que no coincidió con la regla anterior). En este caso, en vez de reescribir, estamos **redireccionando** con `[R]`, así cambiamos la URL a la que se accede.

**Demo**
http://mariano.uphero.com/50400/b/path+con%20espacios#y+hash%20tambien

> **Otra alternativa**. En vez de basarnos pura y exclusivamente en el .htaccess, podríamos reescribir cualquier dirección que tenga un
>   `[+ ]` a un script PHP con
>
> ```python
> RewriteRule "[+ ]" redireccionar.php [L]
> ```
>
> Y encargarnos de reemplazar todos los caracteres deseados dentro del
>   script con [preg_replace()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-replace.php), generando la redirección desde ese
>   script. Esta forma quizás es más sencilla si se complica entender la
>   solución anterior, o puede servir para mantener un log de las
>   redirecciones hechas.

Comment: Muy bien explicado, gracias.

Comment: No se si esto cabe en la duda del OP pero en tú página de ejemplo veo que no funciona el historial, es decir no te deja hacer el `back` ya que toma siempre el filtro, quizás  con [pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#The_pushState()_method) o [replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API#Example_of_replaceState()_method) se soluciona.. igual +1 por tu página de ejemplo :)

Comment: @aldanux Exacto (no es que no funcione, sino que va hacia atrás y vuelve automáticamente). Lo vi, pero no quise complicar más el código ya que hubo demasiados comentarios. Y sí, se resolvería como comentás.

Comment: @aldanux Finalmente lo resolví con [location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Location/replace), que no complica al código y reemplaza la entrada actual del historial.

Comment: Iba a aceptar esta respuesta pero me di cuenta que no era que preguntaba... :)

Answer (score 3):

Creo que con esta simple función puedes reemplazar lo que buscas

```js
function replaceUrl(url){
  return url.replace(/%20|\+/g, "-");;
}

console.log(replaceUrl('http://miurl.com/mi+url+web'))
console.log(replaceUrl('http://miurl.com/mi%20url%20web'))
console.log(replaceUrl('http://miurl.com/mi+url%20web'))
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, pero me surge otro problema lo cual se me olvido indexar en el ejemplo, lo que sucede es que tengo urls manejadas por hash. En este momento agregare el ejemplo de como tengo mis urls

Answer (score 2):

Una adaptación minimizada del código en la [versión 1](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/50407/1) de la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50407/65) de [Jorious](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/18771/jorius)

```js
// http://miurl.com/mi+url+web
// http://miurl.com/mi%20url%20web
// http://miurl.com/mi+url%20web

function replaceUrl(url){
  var fUrl = url.replace(/%20|\+/g, "-");
  return fUrl;
}

console.log(replaceUrl('http://miurl.com/mi+url+web'))
console.log(replaceUrl('http://miurl.com/mi%20url%20web'))
console.log(replaceUrl('http://miurl.com/mi+url%20web'))
```

Explicación

- La expresión regular se expresa entre `/`, luego de la cual se indica el modificador búsqueda global `g`.
- `%20` es una de la secuencia de caracteres, esta se coloca de forma directa
- `\+` se ha escapado el caracter `+`, que corresponde a la otra secuencia de caracteres por ser un caracter especial
- `|` se ha colcado entre las dos ateriores expresiones, para indicar una, otra ó ambas (operador [disyunción lógica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disyunci%C3%B3n_l%C3%B3gica), `ó` (OR) boleano )

Answer (score 2):

Creó que al final lo resolvi, si en algo me equivoco espero me ayude a corregirlo, se los agradeceré mucho, este es mi codigo:

```
String.prototype.regIndexOf = function(regex, startpos) {
  var indexOf = this.substring(startpos || 0).search(regex);
  return (indexOf >= 0) ? (indexOf + (startpos || 0)) : indexOf;
}

function space(){
  var hash;
  if (location.hash.regIndexOf(/%20|\+/g) !== -1){
    hash = location.hash.replace(/%20|\+/g, '-');
  }
  location.hash = hash ? hash : location.hash;
}
```

Comment: En mi opinión es demasiado código redundante. Todo esto se puede escribir en una línea sin que entre en un redireccionamiento infinito --> `location.hash = location.hash.replace(/\+|%20/g, "-");`

Comment: Ya lo intente así pero causa el redireccionamiento infinito, pues utilizo el evento `hashchange`

Comment: Y solo ese codigo me funciona a la perfección.

Comment: El evento [hashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange) sólo se dispara cuando se modifica el hash, y **no se dispara cuando se le asigna el mismo valor**. Es imposible que esté entrando en una redirección infinita. Hay algo de tu código que no estamos viendo. ¿La redirección se genera en JavaScript o en el .htaccess?

Comment: Solo uso javascript, ya que con htaccess no funciona por que después del hash ignora lo demás. Y uso un plugin de jquery que maneja el hashchange.

Comment: Por sierto el cambio de hash también lo manejo manualmente, osea recargando toda la pagina por completo, uso el mismo método de cambio hash via manual y vía hashchange

Comment: Te dejo un ejemplo que muestra que no se genera un redireccionamiento infinito (podés probar manualmente o por consola) --> http://mariano.freevar.com/50400/

Comment: Ok lo voy a intentar.

Comment: Funciona excelentemente gracias.

Answer (score 0):

En mi archivo .htaccess en la regla de re-escritura solo permito solo caracteres alfanuméricos y "+" y "/", al incluir el símbolo de "+" estoy permitiendo espacios en blanco, sin necesidad de reemplazar por "-" caracteres en la URL o de hacer ninguna función adicional en php o javascript, ya que el %20 es un carácter especial codificado automáticamente, al permitirlo en la regla de re-escritura, esta lo decodifique y lo pasa a "$1" ahorrándote trabajo.

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+/]+)$ index.php?views=$1

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9+ <--- "+" espacios en blanco