# Modificar una URL en parámetro de $_GET

Tags: php, php7

Este es el código que utilizo para obtener los datos de `$_GET`

```
  if(isset($_GET['servicios'])){
     $dato = $_GET['servicios'];
     $servicios = $bd->query("SELECT * from servicios where titulo = '$dato'");
     $roww=mysqli_fetch_array($servicios);
  }
```

Como ya muchos saben que una url puede ser `Blog%20Google...` es posible sustituir el `%20` por un guion `-`?. En pocas palabras pasar de `Blog%20Google` a `Blog-Google` ?

Comment: Te dejo aquí un enlace https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50400/como-puedo-reemplazar-20-y-por-en-la-url/50430 xD

Comment: hay dan un cod muy bueno de .htaccess si me elimina el %20  mas no me lo sustituye por un -

Comment: La sustitución también la puedes hacer con javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas vamos por partes:

- Primero, usar parametros sin sanitizar en queries de MYSQL podría ser aprocechado para un ataque de SQLInjection. En tu caso lo ideal sería usar los métodos `prepare` y `bind_param` algo parecido a esto:

```
$statement = $db->prepare('SELECT * from servicios where titulo =?');
$statement->bind_param($dato);
```

- Segundo, `%20` es la representación de espacios.
- Tercero, la función de `urldecode` en PHP decodifica una cadena cifrada como URL, es decir reemplaza estos caractéres por sus correspondientes decodificados.
- Último, si deseamos reemplazar un carácter en un string, podemos hacerlo usando expresiones regulares y el método `preg_replace`.

eg:

```
 echo preg_replace('/juan/', "tio", "hola juan, que tal juan?");
```

La salida es:
`hola tio, que pasa tio?`

Conclusión: Podriamos usar `preg_replace` para reemplazar a nuestro antojo y luego preparar la sentencia SQL para prevenir SQLInjection. Que decodifiquemos o no el parametro antes de usarlo dependerá de tu lógica en la app. Saludos espero que te sirva.

Comment: modifique el query como lo tienes tu

Comment: $servicios = $bd->prepare("SELECT * from servicios where titulo = '$dato'");
$roww=bind_param($servicios); 

y me sale error en la linea 24 -- el cual seria --> $roww=bind_param($servicios);

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplo\infoservicios.php:24 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in

Comment: Warning: Wrong parameter count for mysqli_stmt::bind_param() in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplo\infoservicios.php on line 27

Comment: @programavzla el símbolo de `?` es utilizado para indicar que hay va un parámetro. http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php es la página oficial de PHP en español donde aportan un ejemplo con múltiples parámetros. Si te fijas en mi ejemplo lo uso en vez de $datos.